# Convert string into array using php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am trying to generate the array structure as coding style so it can be used for further development for that purpose i have used following:

```
function convertArray($string)
{
        $finalString = var_export($string, true);
        return stripslashes($finalString);
}
```

It worked fine but the problem is that it adds the additional quotes to the start and end of the value how can i remove these quotes.

Example generated string is as follows:

```
array (
  'foo' => 'array('foo','bar','baz')',
  'bar' => 'array('foo','bar')',
  'baz' => 'array('foo','bar')',
);
```

The string i need is:

```
array (
      'foo' => array('foo','bar','baz'),
      'bar' => array('foo','bar'),
      'baz' => array('foo','bar'),
    );
```

**UPDATE**

Here is how i create my array:

```
foreach( $attributes as $attrib )
    {
        if( $attrib->primary_key == '1' )
            $column[$attrib->name] = array("'$attrib->type'", "'$attrib->max_length'", '\'pk\'');
        else
            $column[$attrib->name] = array("'$attrib->type'", "'$attrib->max_length'");

        $string[$attrib->name] = 'array('.implode(',', $column[$attrib->name]).')';
    }
```

after processing from this loop the final array sent to the above function to convert it into my desired form/

Comment: I just ran your code on my PHP 5.3.10 - it doesn't add any of those quotes. Consider upgrade if you are using older versions.

Comment: you don't want a string, you want an array.

Comment: can you post what is in `$string` exactly that you passed in function?

Comment: i have updated my question if you want additional details about data refer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868245/how-to-manipulate-array-in-php

Answer (score 1):

And you can use backslashes

```
$string = "Some text \" I have a double quote";
$string1 = 'Second text \' and again i have quote in text';
```

And lost variant

You can use 1 idiot variant to create many lines string an in example:

```
$string = <<<HERE
Many many text
HERE;
```

But i dont recommend use this variant

Answer (score 0):

try to use [trim](http://php.net/trim).
Example:

```
$string = "'text with quotes'";
echo $string; // output: 'text with quotes'
echo trim($string, array("'")); // output: text with quotes
```

Comment: trim makes no difference to the output